# Can style of individual features be changed in MapBox?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am loading a line layer from Json data into MapBox. The layer can have many features that connect end to end. I want every other one to be dashed to differentiate when one ends and one starts. Is that possible?  In everything I have run across so far, it requires a data value to do so. There is no value to check. It would just be every other feature in the layer

Answer (score 0):

In your specific use case, there is a workaround.

In your GeoJSON source definition, enable `lineMetrics`: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-lineMetrics

In your layer style, do something like this:

`"line-gradient": ["interpolate",["linear"], ["line-progress"], 0, "blue", 1, "red"]`

Comment: The link you provided speaks to adding a gradient color. I want to alternate the line type style from solid to dashed for each feature. I can't find that information anywhere. I can make the entire layer dashed, but I want that kind of control at the feature level.

Comment: Yes, hence "workaround". For what you want, you need to add specific properties to the GeoJSON features, then use data-driven styling to style them.